# How to wrap object from a promise like an ajax call, difference in the returned value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

This question is similar to '[How to wrap object in a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31107353)', but I need to clarify why I have differences in type of returned values.

Basically, I want to fetch pairs of data from local cache, if not, fetched it from server, store it to local cache. Once the pair of data is stored, then do something else (`doSmtg( stringParameter)`) over the returned arguments - they must be strings parameters, but if hit from cache, they are strings, if from ajax, they are objects.

I don't understand what is the difference.

My code is like:

```js
function promiseContent(nodeId) {

  if (obj[nodeId])) {

  // obj[ nodeId ] is a string: I wrap it in a promise
  console.log('promiseContent hit cache', nodeId, true);

  // make a promise and comply with ajax
  var deferred = jquery.Deferred();
  deferred.resolve(obj[nodeId]);

  return deferred.promise()

} else {

  console.log('promiseContent did not hit cache', nodeId, false);
  return jquery.ajax({
      url: 'url' + nodeId
    })
    .done(function(data) {

      // store to local cache
      // data is a string
      console.log(typeof data);


      obj[nodeId] = data

      // I supposed to return a string object, but actually not ..
      return obj[nodeId]
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      console.log('Error', err)
    })
}

}


function provideExplaination(explanation) {

  // I make an array of promises: I will evaluate results once all promises are completed
  var promises = [promiseContent(explanation.from), promiseContent(explanation.to)];

  jquery
    .when.apply(jquery, promises)
    .then(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

          // if the cache was hit, arguments[i] is a string, arguments[i][0] is null
          // if the cache was not hit (ajax call done), arguments[i] is an object, arguments[i][0] is the html from the ajax
          // 
          // why typeof arguments[i] are different if fetched from cache and returned from the ajax call ?
          try {

            // do something on the result of the promise: it requires a string, not an object
            console.log(typeof arguments[i]) // arguments[i] is a string
            doSmtg(arguments[i], explanation);
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(typeof arguments[i], err) // arguments[i] is an object
          }
        }

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.done()` and `.fail()` methods don't have the same power as `.then()` (and `.catch()` in jQ 3+).

More specifically, with `.done()` and `.fail()`, the input promise is returned, not a new promise therefore these methods possess no "filtering" power; any value or promise returned by .done()'s or .fail()'s callback has no effect downstream in a promise chain. The callbacks are good only for side-effects.

So, in `promiseContent()`, instead of `.done(successFn).fail(errorFn)`:

- **jQuery v<3**:  use `.then(successFn).then(null, errorFn)`
- **jQuery v3+**:  use `.then(successFn).catch(errorFn)`.